# Add an attribute to any java exception

Tags: java, exception, decorator

I would like to customize java exceptions class by adding an attribute to them. It could be as simple as the following attribute:

```
boolean isThisStupid;

void setIsThisStupid(boolean iValue);
boolean getIsThisStupid();
```

Every time I would instantiate an exception, like a NullPointerException, or an IllegalArgumentException, it would contains this attribute.

Since I do not have the source code of Java, I cannot of course edit the Exception base class.

I've considered using the decorator pattern, using an "ExceptionDecorator" class implementing an IException interface, however, doing this I would lose the initial exception type, which I do not want. For example for:

```
IException mException = new ExceptionDecorator( new NullPointerException() );
```

I would get:

```
mException instanceof ExceptionDecorator; //true
mException instanceof NullPointerException; //false
```

I want my custom exception to be an instance of NullPointerException.

This is totally generic, I want this to be working with any subclass of Exception.

Is this even possible ? If yes, maybe there's a pattern which could help me and I don't know about ?

I've done my best to be clear, if I'm not, please ask for more details and I will rephrase the initial topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you all for your answers, it seems like nothing can really satisfy what I need. So I may just change my idea rather than forcing something that would turn awkward and not maintainable

Comment: Excellent conclusion :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want my custom exception to be an instance of NullPointerException.

It is not possible at compile time. To do what you want, you should create dynamically your exception class at runtime with Javasist for example.

Otherwise for static typing, you could use decorators. Decorators have to use the same interface/class than decorated objects. It is the base of the decorator.

In your case, the base class cannot be a new interface you create since you cannot change the code of existing exceptions. So the common abstract class between decorator and decorated objects is `Exception`.

You could have a decorator like that :

```
public class DecoratorException extends Exception{

   private Exception decorated;
   private boolean isStupid;

   public DecoratorException(Exception exception){
     this.decorated = exception;
   }

   public void setStupid(boolean iValue){
      // TODO
   }
   public boolean getStupid{}{
      // TODO
   }

   // get effective exception
   public Exception getEffectiveException(){
     return decorated;
   }

   // decorate the method you wish 
   // for example toString()
   public String toString(){
       return  decorated.toString() + ", isStupid=" + isStupid);
   }

}
```

The idea of Decorator is adding behavior to the decorated object.
 
In my example, I decorated the `toString()` method to display the new field with its value.

You can then rise an exception like that :

```
Exception e = new DecoratorException(new IllegalArgumentException());
e.setStupid(true);
throw e;
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the exception class to extend NullPointer, do something like this:

```
public MyNewException extends NullPointerException
{
    /*define methods and variables*/
}
```

For a class to work with any subclass of exception, you would have to define it as follows:

```
public MyNewException extends Exception
{
    /*define stuff*/
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you want to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here would be to continue with the decorator pattern here as you described, and instead of using `instance of`, create another method in your exception class (`#containsInstanceOf` or something) and using that in your code to check the contained type.

I think the only way to add the behavior you want would be to mess with the byte code like Lombok does, or by creating proxy objects. Both of those are pretty messy and it's probably easier to just use the decorator pattern and deal with the fact that `instance of` won't work.

Comment: I had tought of something like this, but is there anyway to get it to work with try {} catch{} ?